Lagrangian for catenary problem with non-uniform/external force
It is well known that the Lagrangian for the catenary (hanging wire) with uniform gravitational force is.
$$\mathcal{L}=\mu g y\sqrt{1+y'}$$
Now Suppose that there is a nonuniform, possibly external force acting on the wire.
Suppose that force acts purely vertically.
Let $f(x,y)$ be the acceleration field (same unit as gravitational field), then this force can be used to derive the scalar potential (same unit as gravitational potential).
$$F(x,y)=-\int_0^y f(x, \gamma)\,d\gamma$$
Big issue with this is that $f$ may not be conservative over a path in $x,y$ plane, but I feel like this is ok since if we are restricted to only up and downward force, so we effectively made $f$ "conservative" by restricting the allowed path to vertical movement only.
Then the Lagrangian would be
$$\mathcal{L}=\mu F(x,y)\sqrt{1+y'}$$
Is this derivation appropriate? Is there any mathematical flaw?
